# How do I add a string to browser's auto-complete popup?

Tags: javascript

Here is what google login screen looks like:

[image: text suggestions]

you click it and a list of suggestions pops out.

I'd like to do something similar on my own website, where the user would click on the input,  and a list of javascript populated suggestions would pop out (or the list of past searches together with my suggestions).

How can I do this using javascript?

Comment: That looks like the browsers autocomplete

Comment: I believe that this is indeed a browser feature. and has nothing to do with the web site

Comment: can I add items to browser autocomplete via javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a HTML5 `<datalist>` element.

A datalist element allows you to specify a list of values that you want to be in the autocomplete dropdown:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type in here." list="mydatalist" />
<datalist id="mydatalist">
  <option value="Apple" />
  <option value="Orange" />
  <option value="Banana" />
  <option value="Pear" />
  <option value="Kiwi" />
  <option value="Grape" />
  <option value="Grapefruit" />
</datalist>
```

The datalist is defined sperately from the input element. The input element is then linked to the datalist via the `list` attribute which links it to the datalist with the given id.

The `<datalist>` element is only supported in IE10, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera and is not case sensitive (at least in chrome 24). The demo below shows you how to add options via javascript.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ewixoq/1/edit

**Update:** For older browsers that do not support the HTML5 `<datalist>` element,  the jQuery datalist plugin can be used. Link:

http://miketaylr.com/code/datalist.html

Comment: @Robin Updated answer with a polyfill for older browsers

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the native autocomplete feature by adding the autocomplete=off attribute to your input field and you could then implement your own autocompletion. You can't add items to the native list.

Luckily there're libraries out there, which can help you with creating your own autocompletion.
See http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ for example :)

Comment: jQuery's autocomplete is nice, there's also [twitter's typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) which highlights the typed characters in the matched words w/o extending the plugin as JQ UI AC requires.